# What's Java core's official way to create an HTTP connection in 2016?

Tags: java, http, httpurlconnection

I'm looking at [`HttpURLConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html), existing since [JDK 1.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#JDK_1.1), 1997 (almost 20 years now), and I'm quite astonished that it's still Java core's official way to create HTTP connections.

Since it was published, many libraries tried to simplify(/upgrade) the usage of an HTTP connections, like Apache's [HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/quickstart.html).

Other libraries tried to simplify [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) HTTP calls, like [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/).

As far as I could found, no wrapper of `HttpURLConnection` was added to the JDK.

**Is** `HttpURLConnection` **still Java core's official way to create an HTTP connection?**

If not, **what's the official way?**

Comment: If it ain't broke why change it? Old doesn't necessarily mean obsolete, it can simply mean mature...

Comment: So far, I think the answer is yes. Java 9, to be released soon, will bring a new HTTP API.

Answer (score 6):

The old [`HttpURLConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) is currently the standard way to perform HTTP requests in Java SE.

Java EE 7 brought the [JAX-RS Client API](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/package-summary.html), which is the standard way to consume REST web services built on top of the HTTP protocol.

And Java SE 9, to be released in 2017, will bring a [new HTTP client API](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/net/http/package-summary.html) that implements [HTTP/2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540) and [WebSocket](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455), and can replace the legacy [`HttpURLConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) API. The motivation for a new API is described in the [JEP 110](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/110):

> The existing `HttpURLConnection` API and its implementation have numerous problems:
>
> - The base `URLConnection` API was designed with multiple protocols in mind, nearly all of which are now defunct (ftp, gopher, etc.).
> - The API predates HTTP/1.1 and is too abstract.
> - It is hard to use, with many undocumented behaviors.
> - It works in blocking mode only (i.e., one thread per request/response).
> - It is very hard to maintain.

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka The link mentions the following in the summary: *Define a new HTTP client API that implements HTTP/2 and WebSocket, and can replace the legacy `HttpURLConnection` API.* I'll update my answer with a few more details. :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes. `HTTPUrlConnection` is currently the official way. (If by "official" you mean "the way that is supported by the standard Java class libraries".)

Many people / groups have attempted to come up with alternative ways of doing client-side HTTP, with varying degrees of success.  However, the old ("official") way still works, and for a lot of cases it works well enough that there is no need for an alternative.

Java has a strong culture of maintaining backwards compatibility.  If a feature works it is left alone.  Even features that don't work properly are generally marked as "deprecated"<sup>1</sup> if they can't be fixed in a backwards compatible way.  There is a good reason for this.  Oracle earns money on Java from support contracts and specialized products.  Their main customers are Enterprise computing folks.  Enterprise computing folks want the applications that they wrote 20 years ago to continue to work ... without continual tinkering to deal with things that break when the platform (i.e. Java) is updated.

See @Cássio's answer for details of what is coming in Java 9 (next year).

<sup>1 - There are Java APIs that were deprecated in JDK 1.1 ... and still supported.</sup>